# .NET Model item shows up in Input box but not in link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Url that I want to generate like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Id)
@{ var cancel = Url.Action("Index", "KeySetting", new { area = "Document"})+"&Id="+@Model.Id; }
```

However, when I load the page, my `TextBox` is not empty but my `url.action` is missing the `Model.Id` value.

I have also tried this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "KeySetting", new { area = "Document", Id = @Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-secondary" })
```

But my `Id` doesn't appear as well. Why?

EDIT: Route Settings

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "areas",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```

Comment: Maybe you don't see it because you are looking for the Id at the end of the URL, but it actually appears right after the action name (because of the default convention in MVC route config):
`<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="/KeySetting/Index/Id?area=Document">Cancel</a>`
**Id** appears right after **Index/**

Comment: At the moment this is what my url looks like : href="/Document/KeySetting&Id="

Comment: what is the controller's name? Document or KeySettings? Also can you show your RouteConfig settings?

Comment: Sorry the url supposed to be /Document/KeySettings/Index?Id=

Comment: I added my route settings

Comment: Have you tried to omit the `?` in `{id?}`

Comment: Yeah I have. Its just that the Id 's value isn't appearing anywhere that isn't a textbox or hidden value

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to define your view model up top? Sometimes I forget that.

```
@model YourViewModelName
```

Also, maybe try this if you want your id as a route value:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "Edit",
    actionName: "Index",
    controllerName: "KeySetting",
    routeValues: new { area = "Document", id = @Model.Id },
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-outline-secondary" })
```

If you want a query string parameter like ?queryparam=yourmodelid

Try something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "KeySetting", new { Area = "Document" })?id=@Model.Id" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Yeah my model is been defined up top. However its still not showing. It appears the input box though

Comment: Alright well could you mark the question as closed then. Good thing you checked the model. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

No idea why this is not working but this is the best I could come up with. Its not pretty but it works for now. If anyone has a better idea I'll change the tick over to them.

This is what I did:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        var link = $("#@Html.IdFor(x=>x.Id)").val();
        $("#cancel").attr("href", "@Url.Action("Index", "KeySetting", new { area = "Document" })?Id=" + link);
    })
</script>
<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I know what the issue was. My controller was outputing the wrong item. No wonder my Id was null.